# SwiftUI Animation: How to Move THEN Show?

Tags: swiftui

## Example

Here is a menu with three items:

[image: Menu Animation]

This is fine. But what I would like to achieve is:

[image: Ideal Animation]

1. Menu expands
2. Then the three images fade-in **AFTER** the menu is done expanding

I thought maybe adding a 2nd, delayed animation for the opacity might work but instead, it looks like all animation (movement and opacity) gets delayed:

[image: Menu Animation 2]

Here is the code:

```
struct SequenceAnimation_SOQuestion: View {
    @State private var show = false
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 40) {
            Group {
                Image(systemName: "pencil")
                Image(systemName: "scribble")
                Image(systemName: "lasso")
            }
            .opacity(show ? 1 : 0)
            .animation(Animation.default.delay(0.5))

            Button(action: { self.show.toggle() }) {
                Image(systemName: "line.horizontal.3.decrease")
                    .rotationEffect(.degrees(-90))
            }.offset(x: 10)
        }
        .padding(20)
        .padding(.leading, 40)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .background(Capsule().fill(Color.blue))
        .font(.largeTitle)
        .offset(x: show ? -70 : -320)
        .animation(.default)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add each animation **separately**, then you can have different animations for each one:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isMenuCollapsed = true
    @State private var isItemsVisible = false

    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 40) {
            Group {
                Image(systemName: "pencil")
                Image(systemName: "scribble")
                Image(systemName: "lasso")
            }
            .opacity(isItemsVisible ? 1 : 0)

            Button(action: {
                withAnimation(Animation.default) {
                    self.isMenuCollapsed.toggle()
                }

                withAnimation(Animation.default.delay(0.2)) {
                    self.isItemsVisible.toggle()
                }

            }) {
                Image(systemName: "line.horizontal.3.decrease")
                    .rotationEffect(.degrees(-90))
            }.offset(x: 10)
        }
        .padding(20)
        .padding(.leading, 40)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .background(Capsule().fill(Color.blue))
        .font(.largeTitle)
        .offset(x: isMenuCollapsed ? -320 : -70)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what kind of animation you want, but i worked something out which may be somewhere around your goal.

I changed the working of the animations. In your 2nd example your images were animation not right so that's what the following line fixes:

```
struct SequenceAnimation_SOQuestion: View {
    @State private var show = false

    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 40) {
            Group {
                Image(systemName: "pencil")
                Image(systemName: "scribble")
                Image(systemName: "lasso")
            }
            .opacity(show ? 1 : 0)
            .animation(!self.show ? .default : Animation.default.delay(0.5))

            Button(action: { self.show.toggle() }) {
                Image(systemName: "line.horizontal.3.decrease")
                    .rotationEffect(.degrees(-90))
            }.offset(x: 10)
        }
        .padding(20)
        .padding(.leading, 40)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .background(Capsule().fill(Color.blue))
        .font(.largeTitle)
        .offset(x: show ? -70 : -320)
        .animation(!self.show ? Animation.default.delay(0.5) : .default)
    }
}
```

If you provide me a bit more specific information about your goal you're trying to achieve, I can maybe help you.

Comment: Thanks for replying, Tobias. I updated my question to include a mockup of the ideal animation I'm looking for. Menu slides out, buttons appear.